# Delete certain characters from multiple folders using batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename, directory

I really need a batch file to delete the quality, sound profile, and video codec from the folder name..I was thinking a batch file that removes anything after ")" character or delete certain words from folders only.
I have 3000 movies and this would help me soooo much.

I have a bunch of folders named like this

Example:
Carnage Park (2016) 1080p 5.1 x264

Batch file result:
Carnage Park (2016)

p.s
I have searched the site but all I find is ways to rename or delete file names and not folders.
Thanks for the help guys, your the best.

Comment: Does this have to be batch, or would PowerShell be acceptable. String and filename manipulation in batch is needlessly complex, and some things are just impossible without third-party utilities.

Comment: I'll use powershell if necessary

Comment: This is not a site where you can request code for free! Show what you have tried and describe what you have problems with! So please read the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Comment: Ok I'll pay, how much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid errors when some matching dirs are stacked I reverse sort the dir list.

```
@Echo off
Cd /D "X:\start\in\folder"
For /f "delims=" %%A in (
  'Dir /B/S/AD "*(*)*" ^|Sort /R'
) Do For /f "tokens=1,2 delims=()" %%B in (
  "%%A"
) Do Echo Ren "%%~A" "%%B(%%C)"
```

If the output looks OK, remove  the echo in the last line.

Sample output:

```
Ren "C:\Test\blah (2010) blubb" "C:\Test\blah (2010)"
```